# Updating value in temporary table using select statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

```
Insert into #Temp(Rownumber, Percentage) 
select RowNumber, 
       (MatchFirstName.PercentMatch * FunctionWeights.FunctionWeight)
from dbo.MatchFirstName(@FirstName), dbo.FunctionWeights
where FunctionWeights.FunctionName = 'MatchFirstName'
```

In `FunctionWeights` table, I have `weights` column and `FunctionName` column that stores different function names.

`dbo.MatchFirstName(@FirstName)`  is the TVF here. Now , I have a table called `FunctionWeights` that stores a constant value corresponding to these function names.

Before the value is inserted into `Temp` table in `Percentage` column, I want it to retrieve the constant value corresponding to the function name that select statement has and multiply it which percentage value which was retrieved from the function. How can I do this?

With above query, multiplied value is not retrieved in the percentage column of Temp table but only the `PercentageMatch` value from TVF.

SNAPSHOTS:
FunctionWeights Table

[image: This is FunctionWeights table]

select * from #Temp after insert

[image: This is result of select * from #Temp]

The percentage column should have 100 multiplied by the value from FunctionWeights.FunctionWeight. But instead it has 100 in all columns.

Comment: Perhaps you could edit your question with sample data and desired results.  The description of processing is hard to follow.

Comment: @GordonLinoff : Please check. I have updated

Answer (score 0):

Your FunctionWeight for MatchFirstoName is 1, so multiplying with it doesn't make any difference. If MatchFirstName returns 100 in PercentMatch then all rows will be 100.

If you have the fixed function names for the select, you could just fetch the FunctionWeight into a variable before the select.

Comment: No, actually it gives same results for every function when called i.e 100. Values are not getting multiplied

Comment: Are you sure the functions are returning correct values? You could try `select RowNumber, MatchFirstName.PercentMatch,  FunctionWeights.FunctionWeight, (MatchFirstName.PercentMatch * FunctionWeights.FunctionWeight)...' to see what the values are before the calculation

Comment: Yes actually, I am sure that functions are returning just the right values

Answer (score 0):

May be you should give an alias to your TVF and use it to access the column from it, because the reference to the TVF in the from clause includes parameters for it where as the one in the Select clause doesn't.

```
Insert into #Temp(Rownumber, Percentage) 
select RowNumber, 
       (T.PercentMatch * FunctionWeights.FunctionWeight)
from dbo.MatchFirstName(@FirstName) T, dbo.FunctionWeights
where FunctionWeights.FunctionName = 'MatchFirstName'
```